# Recommend programming pattern for Property

Tags: c#, .net

I am good in working with C#. However I am getting confused over a part and that is propelling me to ask this question.

I am having a code as -

```
public class UsersModel
{
public List<string> Users
{
   get
   {
    // Some code to connect to database and get list of users from database
    // return list of users
   }

}
}

public class HomeController
{
   var um = new UsersModel();
   var users = um.Users;
}
```

Now when I check such code from *ANTS Performance Profiler*, I found that the property is hit 2 times and I believe it is impacting performance.

**Questions -**

1. Should I initialize property value in constructor?
2. Or should I create separate method for such task?
3. Why property **Users** is hit 2 times?

**EDIT-**

For reference, I will add link [Property Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.100).aspx) which share good thoughts.

I liked the statement *Property getters should be simple operations without any preconditions. If a getter might throw an exception, consider redesigning the property to be a method.*

Comment: I would end up writing a method instead.

Comment: @ToDownVoter - I would like to understand reason for down vote. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From MSDN ["Choosing Between Properties and Methods"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Do use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations.
>
> - **The operation is orders of magnitude slower than a field set would be**. If you are even considering providing an asynchronous version of
>     an operation to avoid blocking the thread, it is very likely that the
>     operation is too expensive to be a property. In particular, **operations
>     that access the network** or the file system (other than once for
>     initialization) should most likely be methods, not properties.

In this case, you should opt for a method, because a caller of your class will expect a property to return quickly.

Otherwise, a careless caller may haphazardly write code such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < um.Users.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("User {0}: {1}", i, um.Users[i].Name);
}
```

Resulting in `N+1` calls to the database, where `N` is the number of users.

By making it a method, your are shifting the responsibility of caching the result to the caller.

---

> Why property Users is hit 2 times?

I suspect it may actually be a result of a debugger or profiler checking the value of the property. The only way to know as mentioned in another answer, is to check the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

If it takes more effort than simply returning a backing field, then convert it to a method. Especially with database calls, use a method name that makes it explicit that a query is run on a database.

Personally I would add a method to load/retrieve the users from the database, and store that list in the property

```
public class UsersModel {
    public List<string> Users { get; private set; }
    public void LoadUsers() {
        Users = ...
    }
}

public class HomeController
{
   var um = new UsersModel();
   um.LoadUsers();
   var users = um.Users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should I initialize property value in constructor? - not necessary, it depends how you want to use that property.
Or should I create separate method for such task? - For loading the users, yes, you definitely need to create a method. The property should return only the list with the users. Also the users loading method should be async, otherwise it will block the calling thread. Depending on your case you may consider using lazy initialization - to load the users from the db only when you need them. 
Why property Users is hit 2 times? - see the call tree in ANTS that will answer your question.